# Triangle is separated into three triangles, how to calculate their areas?

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

If I have a right angled triangle, with the following vertices

$$v1 = (0,0)$$
$$v2 = (8,0)$$
$$v3 = (0,6)$$
$$v4 = (2,2) \text{ - this point lies within the triangle}$$

I know the area of the whole triangle is $24$. However, I am struggling to calculate the area of the $3$ inner triangles. ($v1v2v4$, $v1v3v4$ and $v2v3v4$).

How can I calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

$V_1V_3V_4$:
$$S=\frac12 2 \times 6=6$$

$V_1V_2V_4$:
$$S=\frac12 2 \times 8=8$$

$V_2V_3V_4$:
$$S=24-6-8=10$$

In another way:

[image]

$$S_234=\frac12 (V_4H)\times (V_3V_2)$$

$$V_3V_2=\sqrt{6^2+8^2}=10$$

$$V_3V_2: y=6-\frac34 x$$

$$V_4H: y=-\frac23+\frac43 x$$

H is intersect of $V_3V_2$ and $V_4H$:

$$6-\frac34 x=-\frac23+\frac43 x$$

$$x_H=\frac{16}5$$
$$y_H=\frac{18}5$$

$$V_4 H=\sqrt{(\frac{16}5-2)^2+(\frac{18}5-2)^2}=2$$

$$S_234=\frac12 (V_4H)\times (V_3V_2)=\frac12 10 \times 2 =10$$

Comment: thanks, if i wanted to calculate V2V3V4 outright, for some reason I get 0.5*6*6, but this seems completely wrong. I get the base as V2V4 which i think is 6 and the height as 6? where am i going wrong?

Comment: @user218210 I updated the answer. Triangle area is 0.5 base times height. Here, 6 is neither base nor height for $V_2V_3V_4$. That is why it does not give you right answer.